# set many to many relations

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have:

```
  @method Users    setMail()         Sets the current record's "mail" value
  @method Users    setUsersGroups()       Sets the current record's "UsersGroups" collection


   public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {

    if($this->isNew()) {

        $this->setMail('test@test.com')); // ok
        $this->setUsersGroups(2);         // doesn't work - error Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an instance of Doctrine_Collection when setting one-to-many references.
    }

    parent::save($conn);


}
```

Table UsersGroups:

```
  user_id
  group_id
```

this is many to many relations.

how can i set users for groups?

example schema:

```
Users:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    mail:
      type: string(255)
    password:
      type: string(255)
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true

Group:
  tableName: group_table
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser

UsersGroups:
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
  relations:
    Group:
      foreignAlias: UsersGroups
    Users:
      foreignAlias: UsersGroups
```

Comment: What excatly do you want to do? Can we see your schema.yml? Just the part of User, UserGroups, and User. If the schema is done right, I don't think you'll have any problem.

Comment: A User does not have a property called UsersGroups you can set to 2. It has a collection of related UsersGroups objects (all those rows where user_id is this user)... it doesn't make sense to set that to the number 2 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {

     if($this->isNew()) {

        $this->setMail('test@test.com')); // ok
        parent::save($conn);    

        $ug = new UsersGroups();
        $ug->setUserId($this->getId());
        $ug->setGroupId(2);
        $ug->save();

     } else {
       parent::save($conn);
     }
  }
```